# « Labeled » en français

Tags: traduction, anglais, science

> Eq. (1) gives the displacement of the particle labeled by X.
>
> Éq. (1) donne le déplacement de la particule...par X.

Quel participe passé interprète « labeled » dans ce contexte ?

Définie, marquée, étiquettée,...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

L'absence de participe est probablement l'usage le plus courant:

> L'équation (1) donne/représente le déplacement de la particule X.

Comment: Dans certains contextes il est aussi possible d'utiliser *notée* ou *désignée par*.

Answer (score -1):

C'est pratiquement toujours « étiquetée ».

Comment: Another negative vote without any explanation...

Comment: @dimitris Should explanations for negative votes be necessarily given? Where? As comments?

Comment: I express myself here. For answers that offer something, I don't understand the negative vote and especially without providing an explanation in the form of a comment. Of course that is mine idea. Not necessarily correct:-)!